# How to escape enum in Swift?

Tags: swift, enums

I had this before, sytactically it is ok, but I need `JSONArray` instead of `Any` as parameter for `enum`.

```js
func `enum`(context: Context, enum: Any, instance: DataToValidate, schema: JSONObject) -> AnySequence<ValidationError> {
  guard let `enum` = `enum` as? [Any] else {
    return AnySequence(EmptyCollection())
  }
```

I tried to rewrite to this:

```swift
func `enum`(context: Context, enum: JSONArray, instance: DataToValidate, schema: JSONObject) -> AnySequence<ValidationError> { 
  guard case .array(instance: let `enum`) = `enum` else { // <----
    return AnySequence(EmptyCollection())
  }
```

but the marked line is not accepted.

[image]

Comment: Why don't just rename enum? Bit odd for a variable name

Comment: Rename the argument `…(context: Context, enum jsonArray: JSONArray, …` so that inside the method you can refer to it to `jsonArray` (or whatever you want it to be named) instead of trying to use a reserved word everywhere.

Comment: Same with `case .array(instance: let ``enum``)`: just use a different name here.

Comment: It is a forked code, would change less as possible ..

Comment: You can try to work around this by adding a `let something = 'enum'` (sorry, wrong ticks), then `guard case .array(instance: let ``enum``) = something`. You're fighting the language parser by insisting to use a reserved word, there's only pain down that road.

Comment: ambiguous name for parameters "enum" is already a used by Xcode and array is also so keep the name like _enum or jsonEnum same as case array to case employeeArray